# If function parameter passes value, how can we hijack the attribute of an object by Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when I'm learning the reactivity in Vue, I can't understand how the reactivity is achieved, if the function parameter passes value.

//the actural code

```
var obj = {a: 'aa'}
function reactive(obj, key, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get() {
            return value
        },
        set(val) {
            value = val
        }
    })
}
function observe(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).map((key, index) => {
        reactive(obj, key, obj[key])
    })
}
observe(obj)
obj.a //'aa'
obj.a ='bb' //'bb'
```

//the error code

```
var obj = {a: 'aa'}
function reactive(obj, key) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get() {
            return obj[key]
        },
        set(val) {
            obj[key] = val
        }
    })
}
function observe(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).map((key, index) => {
        reactive(obj, key)
    })
}

observe(obj)
obj.a //VM1649:6 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

and when I just set value through 'obj[key]', it gives a RangeError

//the example code

```
var obj = {a: 'aa'}
function reactive(obj, key, value) {
   value = 'bb'
}
function observe(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).map((key, index) => {
        reactive(obj, key, obj[key])
    })
}
observe(obj)
obj.a //'aa'
```

however, the example code shows, we can't change the object value through evaluation

Answer (score 0):

In the error code, when you try to get `obj[key]`, it will trigger the getter of `obj[key]` again and again, so it is why `Maximum call stack size exceeded` shows. In the proper way, you should pass value as third arguments in the function `reactive`.